# Why Android Exoplayer hls live streaming not working? link type m3u8

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, live, m3u8

```
Why is Android Exoplayer hls live streaming not working? link type m3u8
Please give a solution
```

https://something.com/test/something.m3u8

### I have used the library

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.18.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.18.1'
```

```
    //pass the video link and play

    MediaItem media = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUrl);
    exoPlayer.setMediaItem(media);
    exoPlayer.prepare();
    exoPlayer.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using hls, I would recommend the hls libraries over the dash:

implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.18.1'

You can find more over here: https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(videoURI)
            .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8)
            .build()
exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
exoPlayer.prepare()
exoPlayer.play()
```